# Vertical-Align Trouble

Tags: css, centering

I'm trying to vertically center something and struggling greatly.

I've gotten my SVG centered nicely, but I've been trying to get my Unorderlist the same for about an hour now.

I'm really not sure which parts of my code to show, so I guess I'll just show all of it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}
#AElogo {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.btn {
  height: 42px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}
.b1 {
  background-color: #581845;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #4f163e;
}
.b2 {
  background-color: #900c3f;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #810b39;
}
.b3 {
  background-color: #c70039;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #b30033;
}
.b4 {
  background-color: #ff5733;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #e54e2e;
}
.b5 {
  background-color: #ffc305;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #e5af04;
}
.b1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #4f163e;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #810b39;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #b30033;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b4:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #e54e2e;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b5:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #e5af04;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
#listrunk {
  font-size: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.listleaf {
  display: inline-block;
}
#parent {
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="AElogo" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.97 68.62">
  <title>ae</title>
  <path d="M96.54,52.37H94.46l0,0.15c-2.56,8.81-8.32,14.18-16.82,14.18-9.91,0-13-7.23-13.52-18.32V39.31H96.56a44.79,44.79,0,0,0-.16-6.22c-0.72-7.2-3.4-12.53-8.26-15.89-3.9-2.7-9.21-4.13-16-4.23H70.24A38.08,38.08,0,0,0,62,14.06c-3.46-8.9-11.62-12-27-12-18.81,0-28.91,5.4-28.91,17C6.11,25.9,9.43,30.6,18,30.6c4.84,0,8.87-2.1,10.85-5.59a10.73,10.73,0,0,0,1.32-5.2c0-.85-0.23-3.3-0.3-4.11,0-.49-0.08-0.9-0.1-1.18q-0.82.06-1.71,0.1c-0.84,0-1.54,0-1.83,0-2.17,0-3.52,0-4.72-.84A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,19.6,11a5.61,5.61,0,0,1,.54-3.44c1.32-2.65,5.78-4,11.15-3.51,5.54,0,7.06,4.57,7.06,22.14V36.83h-4C16.89,36.83,5.48,39.31,3,49.47A19.14,19.14,0,0,0,2.51,54a17.48,17.48,0,0,0,2.14,9c2.31,3.94,6.24,6,10.61,7a32.91,32.91,0,0,0,5.55.72c0.73,0,1.46.05,2.18,0.05h74.5V52.37H96.54Zm-58.2-.46c0,6.51-1.8,10.62-3.79,12.34l-0.23.19a3.22,3.22,0,0,1-1.93.75c-2.63,0-3.6-1.38-3.6-11.34V51.63c0-.39,0-0.76,0-1.13A17.39,17.39,0,0,1,30.43,43a6.89,6.89,0,0,1,4.76-3.69,9.53,9.53,0,0,1,1.59-.21l0.59,0h1V51.91ZM70.29,15.16h0a6.57,6.57,0,0,1,1.09.09c3.43,0.58,4.39,4.19,4.54,13.15,0,0.92,0,1.9,0,2.94V37H64.09V31.33c0-.56,0-1.09,0-1.61,0-.12,0-0.24,0-0.36C64.34,18.7,66.49,15.18,70.29,15.16Z"
  transform="translate(-2.51 -2.11)" />
</svg>
<ul id="listrunk">
  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b1"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b2"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b3"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b4"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b5"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please clarify how it should look like? Does the `ul` have to be on the same height as ae - like behind it?

Comment: no, Im just trying to get the 'ae' ontop of the ul. But still keeping the bunch centered

Comment: Where is `#parent`, `#child`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to put both elements into one div, and then center the div.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .center {
       position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
      }
    #AElogo {
      width: 100px;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
    .btn {
      height: 42px;
      width: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: none;
    }
    .b1 {
      background-color: #581845;
      box-shadow: 0 8px #4f163e;
    }
    .b2 {
      background-color: #900c3f;
      box-shadow: 0 8px #810b39;
    }
    .b3 {
      background-color: #c70039;
      box-shadow: 0 8px #b30033;
    }
    .b4 {
      background-color: #ff5733;
      box-shadow: 0 8px #e54e2e;
    }
    .b5 {
      background-color: #ffc305;
      box-shadow: 0 8px #e5af04;
    }
    .b1:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px #4f163e;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .b2:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px #810b39;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .b3:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px #b30033;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .b4:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px #e54e2e;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .b5:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px #e5af04;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    #listrunk {
      font-size: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .listleaf {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #parent {
      position: relative;
    }
    #child {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 50%;
      height: 30%;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="center">
<svg id="AElogo" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.97 68.62">
      <title>ae</title>
      <path d="M96.54,52.37H94.46l0,0.15c-2.56,8.81-8.32,14.18-16.82,14.18-9.91,0-13-7.23-13.52-18.32V39.31H96.56a44.79,44.79,0,0,0-.16-6.22c-0.72-7.2-3.4-12.53-8.26-15.89-3.9-2.7-9.21-4.13-16-4.23H70.24A38.08,38.08,0,0,0,62,14.06c-3.46-8.9-11.62-12-27-12-18.81,0-28.91,5.4-28.91,17C6.11,25.9,9.43,30.6,18,30.6c4.84,0,8.87-2.1,10.85-5.59a10.73,10.73,0,0,0,1.32-5.2c0-.85-0.23-3.3-0.3-4.11,0-.49-0.08-0.9-0.1-1.18q-0.82.06-1.71,0.1c-0.84,0-1.54,0-1.83,0-2.17,0-3.52,0-4.72-.84A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,19.6,11a5.61,5.61,0,0,1,.54-3.44c1.32-2.65,5.78-4,11.15-3.51,5.54,0,7.06,4.57,7.06,22.14V36.83h-4C16.89,36.83,5.48,39.31,3,49.47A19.14,19.14,0,0,0,2.51,54a17.48,17.48,0,0,0,2.14,9c2.31,3.94,6.24,6,10.61,7a32.91,32.91,0,0,0,5.55.72c0.73,0,1.46.05,2.18,0.05h74.5V52.37H96.54Zm-58.2-.46c0,6.51-1.8,10.62-3.79,12.34l-0.23.19a3.22,3.22,0,0,1-1.93.75c-2.63,0-3.6-1.38-3.6-11.34V51.63c0-.39,0-0.76,0-1.13A17.39,17.39,0,0,1,30.43,43a6.89,6.89,0,0,1,4.76-3.69,9.53,9.53,0,0,1,1.59-.21l0.59,0h1V51.91ZM70.29,15.16h0a6.57,6.57,0,0,1,1.09.09c3.43,0.58,4.39,4.19,4.54,13.15,0,0.92,0,1.9,0,2.94V37H64.09V31.33c0-.56,0-1.09,0-1.61,0-.12,0-0.24,0-0.36C64.34,18.7,66.49,15.18,70.29,15.16Z"
      transform="translate(-2.51 -2.11)" />
    </svg>
    <ul id="listrunk">
      <li class="listleaf">
        <button class="btn b1"></button>
      </li>

      <li class="listleaf">
        <button class="btn b2"></button>
      </li>

      <li class="listleaf">
        <button class="btn b3"></button>
      </li>

      <li class="listleaf">
        <button class="btn b4"></button>
      </li>

      <li class="listleaf">
        <button class="btn b5"></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I present you my solution below:

**Solution**

```css
body {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 text-align:center;

 
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#AElogo {
 width:100px;
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#listrunk {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn {
 height: 42px;
 width: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
}
.b1 {
 background-color: #581845;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #4f163e;
}
.b2 {
 background-color: #900c3f;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #810b39;
}
.b3 {
 background-color: #c70039;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #b30033;
}
.b4 {
 background-color: #ff5733;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #e54e2e;
}
.b5 {
 background-color: #ffc305;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #e5af04;
}
.b1:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #4f163e;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b2:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #810b39;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b3:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #b30033;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b4:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #e54e2e;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b5:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #e5af04;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
#listrunk {
 font-size: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.listleaf {
 display: inline-block;
} 
#parent {
 position:relative;
}
#child {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    

 
  <title>saxonglaser.com</title>
  
  <style type="text/css">

body {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 text-align:center;

 
}
#AElogo {
 width:100px;
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.btn {
 height: 42px;
 width: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
}
.b1 {
 background-color: #581845;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #4f163e;
}
.b2 {
 background-color: #900c3f;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #810b39;
}
.b3 {
 background-color: #c70039;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #b30033;
}
.b4 {
 background-color: #ff5733;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #e54e2e;
}
.b5 {
 background-color: #ffc305;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #e5af04;
}
.b1:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #4f163e;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b2:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #810b39;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b3:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #b30033;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b4:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #e54e2e;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b5:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #e5af04;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
#listrunk {
 font-size: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.listleaf {
 display: inline-block;
} 
#parent {
 position:relative;
}
#child {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}

  </style>
 
 <div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 94.97 68.62" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" id="AElogo"><title>ae</title><path transform="translate(-2.51 -2.11)" d="M96.54,52.37H94.46l0,0.15c-2.56,8.81-8.32,14.18-16.82,14.18-9.91,0-13-7.23-13.52-18.32V39.31H96.56a44.79,44.79,0,0,0-.16-6.22c-0.72-7.2-3.4-12.53-8.26-15.89-3.9-2.7-9.21-4.13-16-4.23H70.24A38.08,38.08,0,0,0,62,14.06c-3.46-8.9-11.62-12-27-12-18.81,0-28.91,5.4-28.91,17C6.11,25.9,9.43,30.6,18,30.6c4.84,0,8.87-2.1,10.85-5.59a10.73,10.73,0,0,0,1.32-5.2c0-.85-0.23-3.3-0.3-4.11,0-.49-0.08-0.9-0.1-1.18q-0.82.06-1.71,0.1c-0.84,0-1.54,0-1.83,0-2.17,0-3.52,0-4.72-.84A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,19.6,11a5.61,5.61,0,0,1,.54-3.44c1.32-2.65,5.78-4,11.15-3.51,5.54,0,7.06,4.57,7.06,22.14V36.83h-4C16.89,36.83,5.48,39.31,3,49.47A19.14,19.14,0,0,0,2.51,54a17.48,17.48,0,0,0,2.14,9c2.31,3.94,6.24,6,10.61,7a32.91,32.91,0,0,0,5.55.72c0.73,0,1.46.05,2.18,0.05h74.5V52.37H96.54Zm-58.2-.46c0,6.51-1.8,10.62-3.79,12.34l-0.23.19a3.22,3.22,0,0,1-1.93.75c-2.63,0-3.6-1.38-3.6-11.34V51.63c0-.39,0-0.76,0-1.13A17.39,17.39,0,0,1,30.43,43a6.89,6.89,0,0,1,4.76-3.69,9.53,9.53,0,0,1,1.59-.21l0.59,0h1V51.91ZM70.29,15.16h0a6.57,6.57,0,0,1,1.09.09c3.43,0.58,4.39,4.19,4.54,13.15,0,0.92,0,1.9,0,2.94V37H64.09V31.33c0-.56,0-1.09,0-1.61,0-.12,0-0.24,0-0.36C64.34,18.7,66.49,15.18,70.29,15.16Z"/></svg>
  <ul id="listrunk">
   <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b1"></button>
   </li>

   <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b2"></button>
   </li>

   <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b3"></button>
   </li>

   <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b4"></button>
   </li>
   
   <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b5"></button>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div> 


    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

</body></html>
```

**Explanation**

I created a `div` that is horizontally centered (`margin: 0 auto`) and has the desired width of the `svg`. Then I set `position` to `relative` that the elements inside relate to it when you use `position: absolute` on the `children` (elements in the container). The z-index let you set the order/layer of the elements (lower values render first - higher values will be on top).

I hope this is what you had in mind. If not leave a comment.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry If my description wasn't too good. I was actually looking to center both the elements vertically one after the other. A post above showed me how to do it, but regardless, thanks for the trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you have `top:0` and `bottom:0` applied to the absolutely positioned svg, making it stretch the whole height of the page and leaving the path in the center of page.

Simply not forcing it to stretch full page by removing `bottom:0` and pushing the list down seems to fix the issue.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}
#AElogo {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  right: 0;
}
.btn {
  height: 42px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}
.b1 {
  background-color: #581845;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #4f163e;
}
.b2 {
  background-color: #900c3f;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #810b39;
}
.b3 {
  background-color: #c70039;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #b30033;
}
.b4 {
  background-color: #ff5733;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #e54e2e;
}
.b5 {
  background-color: #ffc305;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #e5af04;
}
.b1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #4f163e;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #810b39;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #b30033;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b4:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #e54e2e;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.b5:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px #e5af04;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
#listrunk {
  font-size: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  /*height off svg*/
}
.listleaf {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg id="AElogo" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.97 68.62">
  <title>ae</title>
  <path d="M96.54,52.37H94.46l0,0.15c-2.56,8.81-8.32,14.18-16.82,14.18-9.91,0-13-7.23-13.52-18.32V39.31H96.56a44.79,44.79,0,0,0-.16-6.22c-0.72-7.2-3.4-12.53-8.26-15.89-3.9-2.7-9.21-4.13-16-4.23H70.24A38.08,38.08,0,0,0,62,14.06c-3.46-8.9-11.62-12-27-12-18.81,0-28.91,5.4-28.91,17C6.11,25.9,9.43,30.6,18,30.6c4.84,0,8.87-2.1,10.85-5.59a10.73,10.73,0,0,0,1.32-5.2c0-.85-0.23-3.3-0.3-4.11,0-.49-0.08-0.9-0.1-1.18q-0.82.06-1.71,0.1c-0.84,0-1.54,0-1.83,0-2.17,0-3.52,0-4.72-.84A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,19.6,11a5.61,5.61,0,0,1,.54-3.44c1.32-2.65,5.78-4,11.15-3.51,5.54,0,7.06,4.57,7.06,22.14V36.83h-4C16.89,36.83,5.48,39.31,3,49.47A19.14,19.14,0,0,0,2.51,54a17.48,17.48,0,0,0,2.14,9c2.31,3.94,6.24,6,10.61,7a32.91,32.91,0,0,0,5.55.72c0.73,0,1.46.05,2.18,0.05h74.5V52.37H96.54Zm-58.2-.46c0,6.51-1.8,10.62-3.79,12.34l-0.23.19a3.22,3.22,0,0,1-1.93.75c-2.63,0-3.6-1.38-3.6-11.34V51.63c0-.39,0-0.76,0-1.13A17.39,17.39,0,0,1,30.43,43a6.89,6.89,0,0,1,4.76-3.69,9.53,9.53,0,0,1,1.59-.21l0.59,0h1V51.91ZM70.29,15.16h0a6.57,6.57,0,0,1,1.09.09c3.43,0.58,4.39,4.19,4.54,13.15,0,0.92,0,1.9,0,2.94V37H64.09V31.33c0-.56,0-1.09,0-1.61,0-.12,0-0.24,0-0.36C64.34,18.7,66.49,15.18,70.29,15.16Z"
  transform="translate(-2.51 -2.11)" />
</svg>
<ul id="listrunk">
  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b1"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b2"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b3"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b4"></button>
  </li>

  <li class="listleaf">
    <button class="btn b5"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```